# How to expose a Note on a Visualforce Page in Force.com Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, attachment, notes

I'm trying to display all the collateral on a record. I'm using the `CombinedAttachments` relationship in the way below. It works great for `Attachment` if the user has access to the record.

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!combinedAttachment.RecordType == 'Attachment'}">
    {!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, combinedAttachment.id)}
</apex:outputText>
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar for notes but `$Action.Note.View` does not exist:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!combinedAttachment.RecordType == 'Note'}">
    {!URLFOR($Action.Note.View, combinedAttachment.id)}
</apex:outputText>
```

Is there a 'right way' to display `Note` or should I best make a StandardController page and link that?

(So far settling with a custom visualforce page)